# Often memory warning after setting "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.3

I have set "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" build parameter to NO. It has increased the size of my binary app by 0.5 MB. Surprisingly, I have started seeing memory warnings in my application very often. Can this be a reason for this?

I can set it back to YES in that case.

Comment: Corrected the typo. Its 0.5 MB.

Comment: oh, that's a much different size. in that case, the debug symbols are not the root of the problem. run instruments with leaks and allocations to see what can be reduced.

Comment: You may be doing something in your code which enumerates or otherwise accesses the symbols, in which case having a lot more symbols will mean a lot more memory. If not, you should only be increasing memory usage by at most 0.5MB (the space used by paging your entire app into memory, since it's 0.5MB larger).

Answer (score 1):

The debug symbols are not the problem, that is quite certain.

For finding out the root cause of your memory issues, use the following:

1. ***Xcode Analyzer*** - will locate most potential memory leaks already (among other things) without even running your app.
2. ***Instruments: Leaks Instrument*** - will locate all remaining leak issues.

You may, in rare circumstances get false positives from both tools. But rest assured, from my experience those usually are not false positives but spot on issues of your code/app.

Comment: Surprisingly, after turning this property to YES, I see a significant reduction in allocated memory in the instruments. It has reduced by 1.5 MB & I am not seeing memory warning for a while now. So I am changing this parameter back to YES.